# How to use Icon8 webicons in static HTML?

Tags: icons

I am trying to embed Icon8 SVG's in my code

This question relates to this website:

https://icons8.com/welovesvg

I linked to the CDN in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/icons8/bower-webicon/v0.10.7/angular-webicon.min.js"></script>
```

And I put this in the HTML:

```
<webicon icon="material:account-box"/>hello</webicon>
```

But nothing is showing up...how can I make this work?

They also say to link to their website, as I did.

The file on my URL is at:

http://xuzo.com/icon8.html